# can't find ios framework headers in react native module library

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I've included an iOS framework in the xcode project for the React Native module library I'm creating. Everything compiles fine when I build the ios project in the RN library itself, but once I npm install the library into my main RN project, running `react-native link <project-name>`, and then build in xcode, the included framework headers are not found.

I checked the normal build settings (Header, Framework, and Library search paths) and they all have $(inherited) listed.

Repo for the react native library that is WIP  https://github.com/bsy/react-native-pollfish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to make sure that both your Xcode subproject and your main Xcode project both point to a relative path to the SDK.

Steps to take:

1. Open your application's Xcode project.
2. If you don't have a Frameworks group in your project, create one.
3. Open ~/Documents/PollfishSDK using Finder.
4. Drag the `pollfish.framework` file into the Frameworks group of Xcode's Project Navigator. In the displayed dialog, choose Create groups for any added folders and deselect Copy items into destination group's folder. This references the SDK where you installed it rather than copying the SDK into your app.

Answer (score 1):

Please add this line in your package.json file.

```
"rnpm": {
    "ios": {
      "sourceDir": "./ios"
    }
  }
```

Also, unable to install your plugin with "**npm install**".

Comment: Thanks Alex, at the time I wasn't ready to publish yet to npm, it's there now though.

Answer (score 1):

For 3rd party framework set the framework search path in the library project-

$(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/Pods/3rd_party_framework_folder_name

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me for the same problem mentioned in the question.

Comment: I know it has been a long time since you posted this answer, but do you remember what you mean: you say in the library project - does that mean inside react-native-lib.xcodeproj target? or inside the example app that uses that library target? Also, which folder should it point to, wherever the SDK is stored, right?

Answer (score 0):

Download SDK file from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native) . May be owner removes the SDK from github.

Comment: I resolved the issue thanks, it had to do with the path for where the framework was stored on the filesystem

Comment: This wasn't the solution, I'll post it though

Comment: @BenYee ok no problem.